# How do I get the CPU temperature or fan speeds from via terminal or via an Apple API on an M1 MacBook?

Tags: macos, apple-m1, iokit

I tried googling it, but I just found websites that just copy paste each others' content, so basically all of it is "(Intel only)", so I didn't find anything for M1 Macs. There were suggestions using paid apps, but I would be okay just making my own. `sudo powermetrics` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used `menumeters` to get the CPU temperature.

install it using `brew install menumeters`

[image: menumeters - screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much, this shows the commit that enabled to do this: [link](https://github.com/yujitach/MenuMeters/commit/5604e769b9bf5cc0a5ee6f0c6f99ecca570f1b37)

Comment: If you feel this answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark